# Zend_Search_Lucene & accents

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible search accented text with Zend_Search_Lucene? I indexed accented text but the search doesn't find it.

A roundabout solution can be that I deaccent the text before indexing and also deaccent the query string. But it doesn't seam to be an elegant solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to the [text analyzer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.extending.html#zend.search.lucene.extending.analysis). You should use one that supports [utf8](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.charset.html) as the default one converts all text to ascii